# In Nest.js with Sequelize, how to update existing items' ids?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have Next.js + Nest.js + Sequelize project. When I rearrange items by drag and drop in frontend part, I want to update database on Nest.js backend. The repository is gallery.entity.ts which has id, size, type as property. API payload includes only sourceId and destinationId. Then the gallery items between sourceId and destinationId should have updated id. that is to say, the first item of sourceId has destinationId as id. the next item's id is the sourceId, the third item has the second item's id. In this way, I am going to update all gallery items between sourceId and destinationId with one API request. how can I resolve this issue in Nest.js backend? Frontend is ready for API request. I need your hands for only backend side. Basically, I thought transaction would work out in my case. But I am not sure about exact implementation.

**admin.gallery.controller.ts**

```
    @Post('rearrange')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    async rearrange(@Body() sourceId: number, destinationId: number) {
      const result = await this.galleryService.rearrange(sourceId, destinationId);
      return result;
    }
```

**admin.gallery.service.ts**

```
  import { Op, Transaction } from 'sequelize';

...

  async rearrange(sourceId: number, destinationId: number) : Promise<any> {
    let transaction;

    try {
      // start a new transaction
      transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

      // fetch the items
      const items = await this.galleryModel.findAll({
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.between]: [sourceId, destinationId]
          }
        },
        order: [['id', 'ASC']],
        transaction: transaction
      });

      // update items
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
        items[i].id = items[i + 1].id;
        await items[i].save({ transaction: transaction });
      }
      items[items.length - 1].id = destinationId;
      await items[items.length - 1].save({ transaction: transaction });

      // commit the transaction if everything was successful
      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      // if there was an error, roll back the transaction
      if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
      throw err;  // re-throw the error to handle it in the higher layers
    }
  }
```

I want to complete `rearrange` function in service.ts. Can you help me with this?